# Touch-screen equivalent wording for 'scroll'?

Tags: touch-screen, wording

When referring to 'scrolling' up/down a page it is intuitive to use the word 'scroll' on a traditional screen (non-touch), because of the mouse scroll wheel etc.

Is it as user-friendly to refer to the same action using scroll for touch-screens?

e.g.:

- Smart Phones
- Tablets
- Touch-screen computers
- etc

**Is there a better / alternate wording?**

"Swipe down" perhaps?

Comment: The word "scroll" doesn't come from the scroll wheel - the wheel is named after the action. It's a metaphor for moving through a [scroll](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scroll), printed material bound into a long rolled sheet instead of bound into pages.

Answer (score 3):

Based on a quick Google search, the major players are still using the word "scroll" in conjunction with touch screens.

[**Apple**](https://www.apple.com/uk/osx/what-is/) - "navigating your Mac using your fingers to tap, scroll, pinch and swipe feels perfectly natural."

[**Microsoft**](http://www.microsoft.com/surface/en-gb/support/touch-mouse-and-search/using-touch-gestures-tap-swipe-and-beyond) - "How to do it: swipe your finger across the screen.  What it does: scrolls through what's on the screen."

And so on.  I don't think there's any problem with using this term.  "Scrolling" refers to content larger than the screen that you can move through gradually.  It doesn't imply a particular method of causing this action.  You can scroll with arrow keys on your keyboard, a mouse, a mouse wheel, or a touchscreen.

Comment: Thanks for the research! I thought it does make perfect sense to leave it too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can find clarity by asking yourself this question:

**Am I referring to what's happening to the content on the screen or to what the user does to cause that response?**

If you refer to the user's gesture/action, then *swipe* or *flick* is appropriate, but if you refer to the content, then *scroll* is probably a better choice.